# How do I pass a jQuery value to a text box?

Tags: jquery

I have a function

```
$(function(){
    $("#divcalendarcolor  a").click(function(){
        var key = $(this).attr("key");
        alert(key);
        //$('input:textbox').val(key);
        //$('input[id=RemainderColor').val($('#divcalendarcolor  a').val());
    })
});
```

I want to pass the "key value" as the value to a text box.

```
<div class="input text">
    <label for="RemainderColor">Color</label>
    <input type="textbox" id="RemainderColor" value="" maxlength="20" name="data[Remainder][Color]">
</div>
```

Comment: jquery val() function does not work?!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
  $("#divcalendarcolor  a").click(function() {
    var key = $(this).attr("key");
    $("#RemainderColor").val(key);
    //Or you can even use
    //$(input[id = "RemainderColor"]).val(key);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Zpe3U/

```
$("#RemainderColor").val(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

So once you've got the value, just assign the value to the textbox's `value` property using jQuery:

```
var key = $(this).attr("key");
$("#RemainderColor").val(key);
```

It seems your selector might have been a bit off. Remember that you're using selectors which are mostly identical to CSS selectors, so:

- for `id` attributes, use a `#` — like `$("#RemainderColor")`
- for `class` attriblutes, use a `.` — like `$(".className")`
- for `type` attributes, use the `[type=""]` selector — like `$("input[type='text']")`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){

    $("#divcalendarcolor  a").click(function(){
        var key = $(this).attr("key");
        alert(key);
       $("#RemainderColor").val(key);
    })
});
```

Comment: I wish there was a "combine all our answers to create the Captain Planet of answers" button...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to read up on CSS Selectors - your two attempts to set the textbox value won't work:

```
$('input:textbox').val(key);
```

I think what you want here is `input[type=textbox]` which will get all input nodes of type textbox. That won't specifically get the one you want though, so beware.

```
$('input[id=RemainderColor').val($('#divcalendarcolor  a').val());
```

Here you wanted to specify by `id`, for which the syntax would be `input#RemainderColor`.

Apart from the CSS selector syntax, your code is fine. I mocked up am JSFiddle to show it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Se646/